# What is the meaning of these un-common phrases?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

[Source](http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/ruminations/gaon-with-the-wind/)

> Gramted, this is the state government’s prerogative, but does this mean all other villages and towns in India bearing a similar gaon suffix will be grammed down our throats?

In this, only the bold part seems weird.

> If anything, it’s the grams in India that should have been changed to gaons (as in Sevagram to Sevagaon), **although many a lentil would have wondered what comes next. That would have been mean to the bean.** **Wouldn’t Greengram, Horsegram, and Bengalgram panic?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first phrase:

I think *gramted* state govt refers to the willingness of the govt. to change to suffix of the city from *gaon* to *gram*.

Then the 'grammed down to our throats' is just a fun way of writing.It's like 'rammed down our throats'.Since *gram* is being forced upon us, it(the speaker) has said like that.

Comment: "Gramted" is a play on the word [granted](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/granted) which means "admittedly" and it is especially fitting since the name was changed to _Guru**gram**_. If you say _gram_ is the suffix of Gurugram, then yes, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

> although many a lentil would have wondered what comes next. That would have been mean to the bean. Wouldn’t Greengram, Horsegram, and Bengalgram panic?

Lentils are bean-shaped. I don't know if they are technically *beans*, per se, but the author is calling them beans. Also, I believe he is grouping Greengrams, Horsegrams, and Bengalgrams under the name/group "lentils". So if instead the name changes were from *gram* to *gaon*, then these "lentils" would have to worry/panic too because their names would change from Greengram, Horsegram, and Bengalgram to Greengaon, Horsegaon, and Bengalgaon respectively. This would have been "mean to the bean". xD